# Error File "<ipython-input-88-aaa9a8a07a7b>", line 12 y_predict = column_or_1d(y, warn=True) ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This code did not run, it kept giving errors.
The first error was:

> expected 2D while you have 1D

and then the error

> unexpected indent

My code is:

```
from sklearn import metrics
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

    model=LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear")

    #x_train=x_train.values.reshape(-1,1)
    #y_train=y_train.values.reshape(-1,1)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)

    y_predict=model.predict(y_test)
    y_predict = y_predict.values.reshape(-1,1)
     y_predict = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    coef_df=pd.DataFrame(model_coef_)
    coef_df['intercept']=model_intercept_

    print(coef_df)
```

Comment: Did you notice that your `y_predict = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)` line has an extra space at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding the first error

Please check out the dimensions of `x_train` and `y_train` by running

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

The shape of `x_train` should be `(nb_samples, nb_features)`, while the shape of `y_train` should be `(nb_samples,)` - but I am guessing, that the fault lies with `x_train`. Please run each line - one after the other and post, after which line the respective errors appear.

## Regarding the second error

As far as I can see, the second error is because of the indent from the first to the second line. I edited your question so that one can see how you pasted the code into stackoverflow. I am guessing that is your code?